# Common module dynamic backlink

Tags: asp.net, session, url, cookies

It's C# + .net 2.0, but this can be pretty much any environment

I have a list in my website where you can get coming from several different locations (modules). It is a normal list screen, with add/edit (an other) links in it.

You sometimes get here from one module, sometimes from an other module. The only thing that I would like to fix is the Back link. It should always take you back to the module where you came from.

What is the best way to do this?

1. Session variable (this is so far my best choice, but I am not really happy to use this)
2. URL. I could transmit a parameter all over, "carry it with me" (i don't like this a lot because of the number of the pages that are related to this list, I would have to carry that variable with me in add, edit and other screens, too many places to change)
3. cookies ?(limited number of cookies, and things like that, don't really like this one either.)

4-5-6 ?

How are all you guys handling this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the referer in Session and redirect them to this from the back link eventhandler.

This assumes you are doing nothing funky with the querystring.

I have concerns myself about using Session to store information but for this scenario, it is perfectly acceptable.

Cookies are another option, but overkill, unless you factor in the possibility of losing session information on website/app-pool recycle